# Error cuando voy a pasar de ventana Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Buen día compañeros estoy realizando mi primera aplicacion en Android y estoy presentando el siguiente problema al cambiar de ventana, quiero decir al momento de oprimir el boton de confirmar trabajos el error que me muestra es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me sale en la terminal del Android Studio es el siguiente:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.miaasas/com.example.hp.miaasas.marcasymodelosActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #314: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #314: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.hp.miaasas.marcasymodelosActivity.onCreate(marcasymodelosActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

El error me indica que es en **marcasymodelosActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hp.miaasas;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class marcasymodelosActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView seleccionado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marcasymodelos);

        seleccionado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvseleccion);
```

Comment: De lo que se ve en el log tienes un ImageButton en el layout activity_marcasymodelos que falla. Revisa el xml y si quieres publícalo en tu post.

Comment: Revisa lo que carga tu ImageButton, la imagen, selector, statelistanimator, etc que carga tiene el problema ya que le puede faltar un recurso o una propiedad es incorrecta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se especifica como:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #314:
>   Error inflating class ImageButton

No puede inflar la vista `ImageButton`, esto sucede ya que alguna de sus propiedades es incorrecta, generalmente es alguna "imagen" que tratas de cargar en la vista que en realidad no es una imagen o la imagen que puede ser un vector asset tiene dentro un error, regularmente causado que no encuentra un recurso.

```
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_elevation_selector" />
```